# One or more of the Cache Types are invalidated: Blocks HTML output

Tags: magento, caching

I just installed the mageneto and added my first product. It didn't show up in the font page so I went to `inventory` on product information and tried to set `Stock Availability` to `in stock` but I started getting this error message:

> One or more of the Cache Types are invalidated: Blocks HTML output.
>   Click here to go to Cache Management and refresh cache types..

I did this several times, logged and tried again but it appear every time I try to change `Stock Availability`.

How do I fix this?

Googling I fond that's a common issue on mageneto and found [this](https://codeload.github.com/tomasinchoo/Inchoo_InvalidatedBlockCacheFix/zip/1.0.0) exntension and installed following [this instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874761/installing-magento-plugins-without-using-magento-connect) but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Step:01

```
System==> Index Management==>Select All ==>Actions(Reindex)==>Submit
```

Step:02

You may delete cache directory contain all file

```
magento directory\var\cache\
```

Step:03
Another way You may clean database log table

```
#Must Be take Backup before do it:
TRUNCATE TABLE dataflow_batch_export;
TRUNCATE TABLE dataflow_batch_import;
TRUNCATE TABLE log_customer;
TRUNCATE TABLE log_quote;
TRUNCATE TABLE log_summary;
TRUNCATE TABLE log_summary_type;
TRUNCATE TABLE log_url;
TRUNCATE TABLE log_url_info;
TRUNCATE TABLE log_visitor;
TRUNCATE TABLE log_visitor_info;
TRUNCATE TABLE log_visitor_online;
TRUNCATE TABLE report_event;
TRUNCATE TABLE  log_customer;
TRUNCATE TABLE  log_quote;
```

Comment: Neither worked. :-( The error came back after I try to set `Stock Availability´

Comment: When I set Stock Availability it doesn't give any error but the value doesn't change either

Comment: There is a setting for that. It's System->Configuration->Inventory->Stock Options->Set Items' Status to be In Stock When Order is Cancelled. Set that to Yes and clear the cache.Another may your DB user have no update permission

Comment: It's already set to yes. The DB user has all permissions too.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to flush the cache and after that it was fine.[cache error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Etp2U.png)

[flushed cache error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNZ7f.png)

Comment: This post isn't an actual attempt at answering the question. Please note [StackOverflow doesn't work like a discussion forum](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), it is a Q&A site where every post is either a question or an answer to a question. Posts can also have [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) - small sentences like this one - that can be used to critique or request clarification from an author. This should be either a comment or a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)